# What is the placement of the verb in this sentence?

Tags: verb

The sentence is:

> Jemand oder etwas hat mir einen Schlag auf den Kopf gegeben, *als ich in die Grotte gegangen* **bin**.

So my question is, why the verb "bin" is carried out to the end of the sentence? Is it something like weil rule or something? If so, when does that happen when I use als?

Comment: Satzanfänge und engl. I bitte groß und Satzzeichen nicht unterschlagen.

Comment: Please check your grammar (book, favorite website...) for "Hauptsatz" and "Nebensatz".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Als" is a subordinating conjunction just like "weil" is. It's not called the "weil rule" but the same rule governs "als" and "weil," which begin subordinate clauses.

In a subordinate clause, the verb(s) go(es) last. In this case, there are two verbs, so the "helping" verb, bin, goes last, and the main verb, gegangen, goes next to last, preceding only the helping verb.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it has the same reason as with `weil`, but there is no `weil`-rule. The basic reasoning is the difference of coordinating and subjugating konjunctions resp. main clauses and subclauses.

As Stephie suggested, refer to your grammar reference for explanations of these German grammar aspects.